# How can I hide/show a data that in a series? (highchart)

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

I know how to hide a whole series,but I have no idea about how to hide a specific data in a series. here is part of my option:

```
series: [
    {
      data: [
        { x: 35, y: 35, z: 50.8, name: "A" ,visible:false},
        { x: 25, y: 75, z: 50.8, name: "B" },
        { x: 45, y: 55, z: 50.8, name: "C", color: "red" }
      ]
    }
```

[mydemo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-highchart-jjzjx118-ttmbbe)
visible:false is half works  , the background is disappeared but the datalabel is still there , I want hide it , and no user interaction.

and I want tigger hide/show on a bubble click like this:

```
  const onClickBubble = event => {

    let currentPointName = event.point.name;
    console.log(chartRef.current.chart.series[0].options.data);
    option.series[0].data.forEach(element => {
      if (currentPointName === element.name) {
        element.color = "green";
      } else {
        //hide other bubble here
        element.visible = false;
      }
    });

    let NewOptoin = Object.assign({}, option);
    setOption(NewOptoin);

  };
```

so this :

```
events: {
    load: function(){
      var point = this.series[0].points[0];
      ['graphic', 'dataLabel'].forEach(function (key) {
          if (point[key]) {
              point[key].hide();
          }
      });
    }
  }
```

there is no series[x].points in chart option. so this way may not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide a point in the `load` event:

```
chart: {
  events: {
    load: function(){
      var point = this.series[0].points[0];

      ['graphic', 'dataLabel'].forEach(function (key) {
          if (point[key]) {
              point[key].hide();
          }
      });
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4805/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#hide

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load

Comment: thanks for your answer, I want trigger hide/show on click bubble. like this:`const onClickBubble = event => {  chartConfig.series[0].data.forEach(element => {
   // console.log(element.name)
   if (element.name != event.point.name) {
    console.log('hide:',element.name)
    // element.dataLabels.enabled = false;
    // element.color = "#B94E3D00";
    element.visible = false;
   }else{
    // console.log('show:',element.name)
    // element.dataLabels.enabled = true;
    // element.color = "#B94E3D";
   }
  });

Comment: Hi @jjzjx118_2, You need to get the chart reference and call the function on a series point.